# LDAP user invalid for chown

Tags: ldap, pam

My setup is as follows: I have a web application that creates user entries in an LDAP directory. Then, it calls a script which makes the created user the owner of a file.

I have set up an LDAP, and the created users are showing in `getent passwd`. However, the `chown` fails, complaining about an “invalid user”. What may I be missing?

LDAP entry:

```
dn: sn=rabe,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org
sambaLMPassword: 01FC5A6BE7BC6929AAD3B435B51404EE
sambaPrimaryGroupSID: S-1-5-21-3583809738-3196142711-508974553-100
displayName: Testaccount Rabe
sambaLogonScript: _rabe.bat
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
userPassword:: e1NIQX1xVXFQNWN5eG02WWNUQWh6MDVIcGg1Z3Z1OU09
uidNumber: 1004
uid: rabe
cn: rabe
sambaPwdLastSet: 1507196636
loginShell: /bin/false
sambaAcctFlags: [UX         ]
gidNumber: 100
sambaPwdMustChange: 2147483647
sambaNTPassword: 0CB6948805F797BF2A82807973B89537
gecos: rabe
sambaSID: S-1-5-21-3583809738-3196142711-508974553-{uidNumber*2+1000}
description: LDAP Group
homeDirectory: /home/rabe
sambaKickoffTime: 0
sn: rabe
sambaPasswordHistory: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 000000000000000000
sambaLogonHours: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: 737627e0-3dfd-1037-980f-b9017388453e
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
createTimestamp: 20171005094356Z
entryCSN: 20171005094356.722950Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
modifyTimestamp: 20171005094356Z
```

User is listed in `getent passwd`:

```
me@host:~$ getent passwd|diff /etc/passwd -
40a41
> rabe:x:1004:100:rabe:/home/rabe:/bin/false
```

However, `chown` fails:

```
me@host:~$ touch test
me@host:~$ chown rabe test
chown: ungültiger Benutzer: »rabe“
```

**What may I be missing?** What can I check next?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial
File system: ext4

Comment: What LDAP client are you using in nsswitch?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to restart the following services:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/portmap restart
sudo /etc/init.d/libnss-ldap restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Another time, uninstalling and re-installing the `libnss-ldap` package did the job.

```
sudo apt-get purge libnss-ldap
sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap
```